# Create a checkerboard or "Interweave" two linked-lists. IE changing the pointers of two linked lists

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

So I have two linked lists, each holding a color:

---

1.black->2.black->3.black->4.black->5.black->NULL

1.red  ->2.red  ->3.red  ->4.red  ->5.red  ->NULL

---

I want the function to return

---

1.black->2.red  ->3.black->4.red  ->5.black->NULL

1.red  ->2.black->3.red  ->4.black->5.red  ->NULL.

---

Lets name the first pointers, firstBlack and firstRed. To achieve this "checkerboard" pattern, I switch the nodes that each first is pointing to with a simple swap to the other list, advance the pointer two spots, then repeat until I'm at the end of the list.

```
while(firstBlack->next != NULL && firstRed->next != NULL) {
   Node * temp = firstBlack->next;
   firstBlack->next = firstRed->next;
   firstRed->next = temp;

   firstBlack = firstBlack->next->next;
   firstRed = firstRed->next->next;
}
```

However, the function isn't doing what it's supposed to although I'm fairly certain that my logic is correct. I am also getting seg faults :(

Comment: Bring out a pencil and some paper and solve it by drawing boxes and arrows first.

Comment: I have, which is why I'm confident in this logic. However, I am just unsure if my implementation is correct.

Comment: Verify the implementation by drawing that and comparing to your working solution. (It skips too far ahead.)

Comment: Note that after one iteration, the names `firstBlack` and `firstRed` are *completely* wrong for what they point to. `firstBlack` points to the 3rd element of red, and `firstRed` points to the 3rd element of black

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple enough code, please use a debugger and debug the code step by step.
Also please post the entire code not just what's in the while loop.

This code should work correctly.

```
//Some methods to create these linked lists.
pBlackHead = CreateBlackList();
pRedHead = CreateRedList();

firstBlack = pBlackHead;
firstRed = pRedHead;

while(firstBlack->next != NULL && firstRed->next != NULL){
Node * temp = firstBlack->next;
firstBlack->next = firstRed->next;
firstRed->next = temp;

firstBlack = firstBlack->next;
firstRed = firstRed->next;}
```

While printing the list to check the correctness use `pBlackHead , pRedHead`. A debugger is not currently available on the system I am using but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are advancing two steps without checking end conditions. Because you have an odd number of items, you dereference a null pointer.

You don't need to care which tail originated in which list to swap them

```
for(; left->next && right->next; left = left->next, right = right->next) {
    std::swap(left->next, right->next);
}
```